# process dirty memory too large

Tags: c++, c, memory

My online service has a problem, the process memory sometimes goes too large within a few seconds after reloading(2GB or more, the normal process should only take about 300MB resident memory), then it goes stable like other brother processes.
I use pmap -x pid to checkout the memory usage, and found that a huge block of allocated resident dirty memory(which is both private and shared).
I tried to use google tcmalloc to replace the system malloc, changing tcmalloc code to make it abort when allocate  memory size larger than 5MB:

```
inline void* do_malloc_or_cpp_alloc(size_t size) {
/* test */
if (size >= 1024*1024*5) {
    abort();
}
/* test */
  return tc_new_mode ? cpp_alloc(size, true) : do_malloc(size);
}
```

Then I linked tcmalloc in online environment, but couldn't get any core_dump file while the same situation happen again...

Can anyone give me a clue how to solve a problem like this?

Comment: That means you have lots of small (less than 5MB) mallocs. If your program doesn't need 2G memory, there could be memory leak, which can be diagnosed by valgrind, not tcmalloc.

Comment: But My service need at least 4MB malloc to initialize... 5MB is the smallest value I can set, yes it could be memory leak, I've tried valgrind,but couldn't find the cause of the leak...